# Superman as a teenager long before Smallville -- was this in the George Reeves version?

Tags: story-identification, superman

I remember being thrilled as a youngster myself seeing a young Superman I think being frustrated by the necessity of hiding his powers (like while playing football). I am sure this has since the 1950s version been dealt with -- maybe in one of the Chris R. movies but what I think I remember is that the 1950s version actually had an episode with a young Clark Kent -- am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very first episode of the George Reeves series, "Superman on Earth" has a 12yo Clark Kent discussing with his mother was is he so different than other boys and girls. He mentions playing a baseball game in school and they lost the ball. Clark finds it behind a rock by looking through the rock. https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4npm2p

Comment: Yes! Not quite as I remember it -- I thought there was a scene with him throwing a ball but that could be a later Superman version. Crazily bad dialog: Fetching baby Superman from flaming rocket, Eben Kent hands it to Sarah who peaks at the swaddled infant. Eben asks cheerfully, "Burnt much?" and Sarah reports neither he nor the blanket at burnt at all. *Burnt much?* -- wow. I think the actor who played teenage Clark is still alive. Also, the crap Jor-El had to put up with from his fellow council members. One calls him jeeringly "Mr. Scientist."

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you may be thinking of [*The Adventures of Superboy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Superboy) from 1961, starring Johnny Rockwell.

[image: Johnny Rockwell as Superboy]

> ***The Adventures of Superboy*** is a proposed TV series that was put into production in 1961. It was meant to capitalize on the success of *Adventures of Superman*, which went out of production in 1958. Only a pilot episode ("Rajah's Ransom") was produced, although 12 additional scripts had been prepared, had the series been picked up.
>
> It featured the first non-comic book portrayals ever of Superboy and Lana Lang and stands as a forerunner of later series *Superboy*, which lasted four seasons and *Smallville*, which lasted ten seasons.

Searching for *teenage superman* suggested *who played teenage superman in 1978*, which led to [this entry in the "Every Actor Who's Ever Played Superman](http://www.zimbio.com/Every+Actor+Who%27s+Ever+Played+Superman/articles/MoIqN0Iw1Ue/Johnny+Rockwell) list.

### Pilot

Comment: Thanks very much for this -- this doesn't seem to contain the scene I remember but date would have worked, existed when I was a little kid. Crazy show, weirdly mundane. Donna is very attractive. I think the cast is interesting: some are still alive but none I think worked much after the 1960s. One has the last name Reeves but no relation according to bio. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0159238/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast